# SUBSTITUTE function google sheets doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, replace, syntax, google-sheets-formula, substitution

As far as I know, this is the right way to use the SUBSTITUTE function, but the formula gives a parse error. What did I do wrong?

[image: Example]

Comment: Google sheets uses semicolons as parameter separators in certain countries in Western Europe, rather than commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A33; "1"; )
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is working. I always used a comma, but changed language recently to english. Now I have to use semicolons.